# MYSQL Getting a balance from sum payment and sum charges from 2 seperate tables and updating it to a 3rd table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, sum

I have 3 tables, ChargeTable, PaymentTable, CustomerTable.

ChargeTable has CustomerID, ChargeAmt

PaymentTable has CustomerID, PaymentAmt

CustomerTable has CustomerID, Balance

I need to seperate them by CustomerID, Add up the sums, then subtract payments from charges to get the balance, and finally post it into CustomerTable.Balance.

I am new to SQL and have been fiddling with this for hours, i can get pieces to work, but never the whole show. Any one have a good efficient solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO CustomerTable (CustomerID, Balance)
SELECT a.CustomerID, SUM(a.Amount) FROM
(
SELECT ct.CustomerID, ct.ChargeAmt as Amount FROM ChargeTable ct
UNION ALL
SELECT pt.CustomerID, -pt.PaymentAmt as Amount FROM PaymentTable pt
) a
GROUP BY a.CustomerID
```

Comment: Not sure which DB you meant - mysql or sqlserver but this query should work on any SQL DB

Comment: I am getting  #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY', Is this updating both customer id and Balance?

Comment: Created a separate table BalanceT. and this code placed it in there correctly, not exactly what i was after, but had a conflict with the primary key of other table.

Comment: This is a query for inserting records. You should have been more clear in your question whether you want insert or update. "post" is not an SQL term.